# Protect a Github branch using Github APIs

Tags: git, github, github-api

I am really new to Github APIs.

I have to create a script (shell/Groovy) that can enable protection on branches of multiple repos in one go so that just the authorized users can access it.
Although I have read the [documentation](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#get-branch-protection) but it's not very clear to me how to implement it.

Comment: May we see the code you have at present, to see where you are getting stuck? If you do not have any code currently, it would be best to make a partial try, so that readers can see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The actual API would be "[Update branch protection](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/branches/#update-branch-protection)"

```
PUT /repos/:owner/:repo/branches/:branch/protection
```

Use a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line) with an [associated scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/#available-scopes) of [at least `public_repo`](https://github.com/google/go-github/issues/625#issuecomment-298063138)